# EC2 can an IP assigned to an instance while it was launched be made static(ElasticIP)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I launched a micro instance on Amazon EC2, it was assigned a public IP which was picked up from a pool of available IP basically DHCP.

Now I want to assign a static IP to this instance.

EC2 to has a way of doing this but with that approach I will loose the current IP address and I will be given a new one, the problem is I have used the current IP address in all my code.

So is there a way in which the IP address assigned to the instance be made static IP?

Comment: Any half decent IDE should make it easy to search for references to the IP in your project and replace them with a config derived variable.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. According to Amazon:

> .. an instance can only have one Internet routable IP address. If an Elastic IP is mapped to an instance its existing Public IP address mapping is removed.

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346

and BTW, hard coded IP's in your code is a very bad idea.

Comment: An added note is that all ec2 instances have an API by which you can retrieve metadata about the instance (including IP address).  This is accessed via a simple RESTful call. Rather than hard-coding IP address you might want to look at making a call to this API and caching the result for use in your app. Here is URL with info: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html

Answer (score 0):

What Brennan said is right you cant do it. Its a bad idea to hard code to ip address, what we do is we assign a domain or a subdomain or even hard code it some times. Though my IP address changes, I just to change my A record.